# Remove post navigation links

Tags: comments

I'm using my own Theme, i'v read this references. For comments I'm using comments.php template which is located in my theme folder, but there isn't code in comments.php which create navigation links, actually between header and main content.

Comment: if you are on looking to to remove them from the single post view then its most likely on your theme single.php file but knowing what theme you are using woud help.

Answer (score 1):

First, it would be very helpful to know what Theme you're using, so that we can give specific instructions/advice.

Without knowing what Theme you're using, we have no way of knowing what template file(s) to tell you to edit; however, those links are likely coming from these two tags:

`previous_post_link()` ([Codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link))

and

`next_post_link()` ([Codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link))

Comment: ...and do you find these two functions in the relevant template file(s) in your Theme?

Comment: EDIT: my comment makes no sense; since it appears that you deleted your comment, which was: *I'm using my own Theme, i'v read this references*

Comment: I'v created my own theme from Starkers HTML5 1.1